# Why is the reason my dictionary ordered in Python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I wanted to see how often a word occurs in tweets from Twitter. I downloaded 500 tweets from Twitter using the Twitter API and made a dictionary with word frequencies as keys and a list of all words corresponding to that frequency as values.

I always thought dictionaries were always unordered, so I wanted to order my dictionary in some way. But when I looked at it, it was already ordered by keys from low to high. How is this possible?

This is the code I used:

```
def countWords(cleanDict):
    reverseDict = {}
    FreqDict = {}
    count = 1
    for tweet_id in cleanDict:
        tweet = cleanDict[tweet_id]
        wordList = tweet.split()
        for word in wordList: # Creates a dictionary with words as keys and
                              # frequencies as values
            if word in reverseDict:
                reverseDict[word] += 1
            else:
                reverseDict[word] = 1
    for word in reverseDict: # Creates a dictionary with frequencies as keys and
                             # lists of words as values
        if reverseDict[word] in FreqDict:
            temp = FreqDict[freqDict[word]]
            temp.append(word)
            FreqDict[freqDict[word]] = temp
        else:
            FreqDict[freqDict[word]] = [word]
    return FreqDict

countWords(cleanDict) # cleanDict is a dictionary with tweet ID's as keys and
                      # tweets as values
```

Don't get me wrong; it's wonderful that my dictionary is already ordered like this, but how?
Is it the way I add to the dictionary or something?

I tried making a dictionary with integers as keys and some strings as values. I added the keys in no particular order, but when I printed this dictionary it was ordered by keys again.
Is this something Python always does?

Comment: what is the order they are downloaded in?

Comment: How do you _know_ it's ordered?  Where are you viewing it?  How is it displaying?  The underlying representation is unordered, but that doesn't mean that something else can't represent it in an ordered manner.

Comment: @Drewdin The last tweet downloaded is the last tweet posted. The second last downloaded is the second tweet last tweet posted and so on all the way to the 500th tweet

Comment: @g.d.d.c I just printed it to my shell

Answer (score 8, accepted):

"Unordered" is a misnomer; they are *arbitrarily* ordered, left up to the implementation.  Specifically, the ordering is guaranteed to be arbitrary, but consistent (within a single instance of a Python interpreter [1]).

As to why you are getting that behavior, you are using `int`s for your keys.  It so happens that in [CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython), the `hash` of an `int` is itself.  Thus this:

```
d = dict(zip(range(100),' '*100))
print(d)
```

Will always come out with the keys in numeric order, thanks to that implementation detail.  But this:

```
d = dict((L, i) for i, L in enumerate('abcdefg'))
print(d)
```

will (very probably) not print out in alphabetic order.

---

[1] String hashing behavior *can* vary from interpreter instance to instance, depending on what version of Python you're running.  Python 3 introduces a "random seed" to the hashing of string keys as something of a security measure.  You can enable that behavior on Python 2.7 with `python -R`.

Comment: It's worth noting that even with integers, you're only likely to get an exact ordering if your numbers are relatively tightly packed and start near zero. If you use a different range than the `0` to `100` in your example, you may or may not end up with ordered keys. `dict(zip(range(200, 300), " "*100))` for instance, starts with key `256`, not with `200`.

Comment: Oh, how strange. I didn't realize it wouldn't work the same in Python 2. The reason it happens in Python 3 is that the hashes (which are equal the the keys) cross an exact multiple of the underlying hash table size. The actual hash-table indexes are the hashes, mod the table size, so this means some values end up out of order. I suspect the same thing can happen in some way in Python 2, unless there's some deliberate hack to make it stay ordered that I don't know about. With very-widely distributed numbers you might be able to get strange orders due to hash collisions!

Comment: @Blckknght Interesting.  I thought about this overnight and you're right - for small dicts in py3, the ordering appears to be consistent with `key % 256`, i.e. 8-bit hash table.  I just checked and the next step up is a 10-bit table, so `key % 1024`.  So really the anomaly is python 2 - I'm curious enough to keep investigating and maybe post a question if I can't figure it out on my own.

Comment: Ah, and there it is - `dict(zip(range(1000,2100), ' '*1100))` appears to exhibit `key % 2048` ordering in python 2.  So really it's just that hash tables start at 11 bits in py2, and 8 in py3.  Whew.

Comment: It varies with the number of values you put in the dictionary. Try a dict with fewer than 6 items, and keys of 7 and 8 and you'll get 8 before 7 when iterating in both Python 2 and 3. I think the differences we've been seeing between versions have to do with where exactly the boundaries are that cause the internal hash table to be resized (or perhaps, how much bigger the resized table becomes).

Answer (score 1):

It might be pure luck. And it might change if you have more objects in the dict and it needs to resize, or if your objects are not created one after another (so their IDs/memory addresses vary more).

If you needed the order, you can simply use `collections.OrderedDict` and have it guaranteed. Or use `collections.Counter` for the task, which is made for this kind of counting.

Comment: Couldn't be just pure luck right? If there where 10 tweets there would be a small chance that the order in the dictionary is actually orderded, but 500?